# android device html5 input type "tel" dont have go button in old version

Tags: android, html, input, tel

In our application we have input type "tel" in android 4.2 device we have go button but in 4.1 we don't have go button so we can't use for search functionally. Any one have alternate solution please give me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use input type `number` there instead when you detect a browser that is 'incompatible' with `tel`?

Comment: Or maybe place submit button

Comment: Thanks we don't want submit button.We want input type with numbers and keyboard must have go button